# Convert argv[1] into an int and it's digits into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, int, argv

I've been trying to create a program in C++ that tries to accomplish this pseudocode:

```
get argv[1] into int

get int’s digits into array[int length]

for int i = array length; i >= 0;

gen random number into check

if check == array[i]
    i
    say Number i was check
end if
```

And I think the part I'm really struggling with is the

```
get argv[1] into int

get int’s digits into array[int length]
```

part. In my full code there isn't even an attempt because nothing I've tried works. The error I get the most is that the code compiles, but everytime it tries to `cout << "Number 1:" << number` I just get `Number 1: 0` no matter the actual number I enter. And when `0 == 0` the code doesn't even notice.

My broken propably convention-breaking code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc == 1 || argc == 3) {
        std::cout << "Argument count does not match (one argument expected)\n";
        return(-1);
    }

    std::cout << "Input: " << argv[1] << "\n";

    const char* text = argv[1];
    int number = atoi(text);

        int check = rand() % 10;

        std::cout << "Check 1: " << check << "\nNumber 1: " <<  number << "\n";

        if (check == array[i]) {
            i++;
            std::cout << "Success! Number " << i << " was " << check << ".\n";
        }
    }
}
```

TL;DR: My "sort of" number cracker doesn't want to put argv[1](https://github.com/jontturi/Compare) into an int with the int's digits being later put into an array.

Feel free to make me feel stupid. Hope the question isn't too specific. I'll expand on details as asked.

EDIT: This is an earlier attempt at conversion:

```
    int array[];
    for (int i = strlen(text); i >= 0; i--) {
        array[i] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
```

EDIT2: So many responses, no solutions. Thank you for trying to explain this newbie so many things at once. BTW: [Git](https://github.com/jontturi/Compare)

Comment: Each char in `text` is an ASCII representation of a digit, right? You could use this to your advantage to place each digit into your int array, instead of using `atoi` first.

Comment: @crush Except I know pretty much nothing of c++ and don't know how to do what you're implying. Although I _sort of_ understand what you're saying.

Comment: first thing would be to stop thinking of a `char` as an `alphatbetic character`. It is really just an 8-bit byte. Your input is from the console, which will always be ASCII unless you are using some modified special console that uses unicode. Check out the following ASCII table if you are unfamiliar with ASCII: http://www.asciitable.com/. Notice how each `character` has a corresponding numerical value. For example, the digit `0` is actually the number 48. Furthermore, strings in C++ are generally terminated by a NUL byte, which has value of 0.

Comment: So say your user entered the number "576". This is an array of `char` which is an array of 4 bytes: `char arr[4] = {53, 55, 54, 0};` The last byte is the string terminator, and is what is checked for to find the end of the string.

Comment: @crush Yay, I learned something new!

Comment: @jontturi sorry for the bump, but I think you didn't read my answer below..

Answer (score 2):

The earlier attempt is almost good: it's just that you have to **actually allocate** space for the array, like this:

```
int array[strlen(text)];
```

if your compiler supports variable-length arrays as an extension, and

```
std::vector<int> array;
array.resize(strlen(text));
```

if you want to stick with standard C++ and follow some good practices.

However, if you want to be tricky, you don't even need to convert the argument to a number:

```
if (argv[1][i] == check % 10 + '0')
```

does the trick too. All in all, the complete program would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int check = std::rand();
    std::cout << check << std::endl;

    char *p = argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]);
    while (p - argv[1] >= 0) {
        if (*--p == '0' + check % 10)
            std::cout << "guessed " << p - argv[1] << "th digit" << std::endl;

        check /= 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm an absolute newcomer into C++, so excuse my stupidity: where do I put this stuff in the code, exactly? Your fix is propably right, but currently adding this on top of `for (int i= strlen`... only gives me the same error I had before. I'm using g++ on mac's terminal.

Comment: @jontturi Which stuff? There are three code snippets in this answer.

Comment: I loaded the page before you had written the last snippet. I'm talking about the first two bits.

Comment: @jontturi You replace `int array[];` by either of them. But anyway, see the edit - you're overcomplicating this way too much.

Comment: Umm, compiling your edit, I'm getting this: `$ ./a.out 7 
16807
guessed 0th digit`

Comment: Aaand I can't put a return there. there are two newlines: after 7 and before 0th.

Comment: @jontturi Well, if the PRNG generated 16807, and you entered 7, then what's wrong with the output?

Comment: @jontturi Also, what do you mean by "Aaand I can't put a return there"? And what's the matter with all with those newlines? Where are they? Why are they relevant at all? I don't follow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we're not on the same page. This program (in its stupidity) is supposed to take in a number (say 7) generate random numbers, and if the random number matches the input, return the random number, which now equals the input. So if I input 7 it should eventually output 7, not 16807.

Comment: @jontturi "So if I input 7 it should eventually output 7" - then what does the random number generation serve for? Why don't you just do `cout << argv[1] << endl;` if all you need is printing reproducing the input verbatim?

Comment: Because I want to try to create this for the sake of creating this and this is experimentation for learning c++. This program is not meant to server any purpose. My idea was "number cracker well sort of".

Comment: @jontturi So how does the random number finally come into the picture? If you really need to reproduce the input on the output, then what are you doing with the random number?

Comment: It's like this: generate a random digit. if random digit equals the first digit of input, success, move on to next digit. repeat.

Comment: @jontturi Ah, OK. So basically you need more than one random digit, right? And you want to check if those matched the digits of the input, right? Then, you remove the `check /= 10` part, and move `check = random() % 10` inside the for loop, that's all. Now think a bit about how/why it works.

Comment: I'm starting to think this will never work, apparently I have the ability to not be able to solve a simple programming problem. Even with help. I put my tries and alternatives from your comment into this: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iDuSs8BQ)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is relatively close to being right. You are struggling with the declaration of the array (you must specify the size for it). 32-bit `int` cannot have more than ten digits, so declaring

```
int array[10];
```

should be sufficient.

Before converting the number to an array of digits, check if it is negative, and flip its sign if it is negative:

```
if (number < 0) {
    number = -number;
}
```

Otherwise, your `number%10` trick is not going to work.

When you do the conversion, count how many digits you have. Put the result in `actualCount` variable: chances are that you are not going to use up all the digits in your array, so

```
int check = rand() % 10; // 10 is the max, not the actual digit count
```

should be

```
int check = rand() % actualCount;
```

Your argument checking also needs improvement: think what would happen if the user passes five parameters? If you expect exactly one argument, you should write

```
if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Argument count does not match (one argument expected)\n";
    return(-1);
}
```

Comment: A pretty good answer, but no need to specify an array the max size when you know the strlen before needing to allocate. =}

Comment: @crush Except that 10 `int`s aren't going to waste memory, and standard C++ doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: @crush `strlen` will be sufficient, but it may not give you the exact number of digits (think of negative numbers again ;-) Ten bytes is a tiny number by today's standards, so using `new[]` and `delete[]` to get the exact number of bytes is unlikely save you anything, especially in architectures where storing a pointer requires eight bytes :-)

Comment: Okay, I currently have this: http://pastebin.com/LsDRZhB9 and the only error I'm getting is (I renamed array to arr) "request for member ‘size’ in ‘arr’, which is of non-class type ‘int [10]’"

Comment: @jontturi C++ arrays have no `size()` function - you can hard-code the size to ten as in the declaration, use a `#define NUM_DIGITS 10` in the declaration and in the loop, or use the array size macro `#define SIZE(arr) ((sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])))`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've added the define num_digits thing and `int actualCount = NUM_DIGITS;`, yet The program still couts "Number 1: 0". The input I used was 7. Apparently my code doesn't wanna work with anything suggested here.

Comment: @jontturi Your code still has some errors: your loop where you divide number by ten should stop when the number reaches zero, with a special case for number=0. actualCount should be the number of digits that you count in that loop: set actualCount=0 before the loop, and do actualCount++ on every iteration.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Now I know my agenda. First I need to learn c++. Then I need to do the stuff suggested here. Trying to do this and knowing bugger-all is not helping my case. See you in ten years.

Comment: @jontturi In ten years you are not going to need my or anyone else's help: in fact, you should be able to answer 80% of SO's questions on C++ after about a year of studying the language. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract only one digit at a time from a number you have a couple of choices.

For convenience you can use a `std::string`, inserting the original string (`argv[1]`) in it, then extracting one `char` at a time:

```
#include <string>

...    

// put the input in a string
std::string text = argv[1];

for (unsigned i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
{
   // extract only one char, a digit
   char ch = text.at(i);
   // convert that char in a number
   int n = ::atoi(& ch);

   // use n
   ...
}
```

If you don't want to use `std::string`, you can always use a c-like array (`argv[1]` itself):

```
#include <cstring>

...    

for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
{
   // extract only one char, a digit
   char digit = argv[1][i];
   // convert that char in a number
   int num = ::atoi(& digit);

   // use n
   ...
}
```